# Trying to find the derivative of a function that depends on the comoving momentum modulus

Tags: cosmology, momentum

How to show that for a function $f=f(P^{2})$ and for $P^{2}=\delta_{ij}P^{i}P^{j}$, we have

$$ P_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial P_{i}} = P \frac{\partial f}{\partial P}$$

Comment: Show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

The question that you are asking has interesting implications. Instead of just stating it, I recommend you check [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar), and improve yours by providing some context around it, like what this formula is used for, the things you have tried in order to solve it and the difficulties you faced.

To solve this, I will start by applying the chain rule,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
P_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial P_i} = P_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial P^2} \frac{\partial P^2}{\partial P_i}.
\end{equation}

Partial derivatives can be somewhat tricky when using Einstein notation, this would be a way to approach it using this property $A = A_\mu A^\mu = A^\mu A_\mu $ that scalars have:
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{eq2}
\frac{\partial P^2}{\partial P_i} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial P_i}(\delta_{ij}P^i P^j) = \frac{\partial}{\partial P_i}(\delta^{ij}P_i P_j) \\
&=\delta^{ij} \frac{\partial P_k}{\partial P_k} P_j + \delta^{ij} P_k\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial P_k} = \delta^{ij}P_j + \delta^{ij} P_k\delta_j^k\\
&= P^i + \delta^{ij}P_j = P^i + P^i = 2P^i
\end{align}

Now, we substitute \eqref{eq2} into \eqref{eq1}, and we get the final answer:
\begin{equation}
P_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial P_i} = 2P^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial P^2} = 2P^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial P} \frac{\partial P}{\partial P^2} = 2P^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial P} \frac{1}{2P} = P \frac{\partial f}{\partial P}.
\end{equation}